# Selecting JavaScript variable and array element depending on user input

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, user-input

I want to select an element from an array depending on user input. An example of how I have tried to do this is below. The user will input 1,2 or 3 (in this example). Then, depending on the result of this input, one of the `a` variables will be selected. Then, a random element from that variable/array will be selected to be displayed in the paragraph tag.

```html
// user input must be 1,2 or 3 (in this example)
<input type="number" id="userInput">
<script>
    var ageNum = [0,1,2];
    var a1 = ["string1.1","string2.1","string3.1"];
    var a2 = ["string1.2","string2.2","string3.2"];
    var a3 = ["string1.3","string2.3","string3.3"];
    var selectedA = ["a"+userInput.toString()];
    var rdnNum = ageNum[Math.floor(Math.random()*ageNum.length)];
    document.getElementById("display_string").innerHTML = selectedA[rdnNum];
</script>

<p id="display_string">...</p>
```

This is just an example I have tried (which failed), but I am open to any new ways of attacking the problem.

Comment: .toString is unnecessary. Only a string can be returned by inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var a1 = ["string1.1","string2.1","string3.1"],
    a2 = ["string1.2","string2.2","string3.2"],
    a3 = ["string1.3","string2.3","string3.3"];


var input = document.querySelector("input[type=number]"),
inputValue= input.addEventListener("input",function(){
    var currentValue = this.value;
    if (currentValue >0 && currentValue <4 ){
         if(currentValue === 1){ /*a1*/}
         elseif(currentValue === 2){ /*a2*/}
         else(currentValue === 2){ /*a3*/ }
    } 
}, false)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="userInput">
```

a cleaner code would be

```js
var a1 = ["string1.1","string2.1","string3.1"],
    a2 = ["string1.2","string2.2","string3.2"],
    a3 = ["string1.3","string2.3","string3.3"];

 
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=number]"),
inputValue= input.addEventListener("input",function(){
    var currentValue = this.value;
    if (["1", "2", "3"].includes(currentValue)){
        
         var myArray = "a"+currentValue;
          alert(myArray);
    } 
}, false)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="userInput">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should handle a two dimensional array to easily get the respective message.
DOM elements are event-based. So, you should use Event Listeners.

```
var msgs = [
["string1.1","string2.1","string3.1"], // a1
["string1.2","string2.2","string3.2"], // a2
["string1.3","string2.3","string3.3"]  // a3
];

document.getElementById('userInput').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var selectedArray = msgs[parseInt(e.target.value)];
  var randomIdx = parseInt(Math.random() * selectedArray.length);
    var randomMessage = selectedArray[randomIdx]
    document.getElementById("display_string").innerHTML = randomMessage
});
```

[Check this fiddle to see my approach](https://jsfiddle.net/t7qtqae3/5/)